# Getting the right data context in a Meteor template event handler

Tags: templates, events, meteor

I am using Meteor 1.3.1, and I am doing some experiment to fetch the data context in the events listener block, here is my code:

```js
  

var objs=[ 
      { a:"a1", b:"b1", yes:true },
      { a:"a2", b:"b2" },
      { a:"a3", b:"b3", yes:true },]


Template.tt.helpers({
  objs: objs
})

Template.tt.events({
  'click .b'(event, template) {
 console.log(Template.currentData().a);   //---> undefined
 console.log(template.data.a);            //---> undefined
    console.log(Template.parentData(0).a);   //---> undefined
 console.log(this);                       //---> Window Obj
  } 
})
```

```html
<template name="tt">
{{#each objs}}
  <h1>a={{a}}, b={{b}}</h1> 
  {{#if yes}}
    <button class="b">b</button>{{yes}}
  {{/if}}
{{/each}}
</template>
```

I want to get the value of the `a` key, but failed in several ways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The common pattern for this problem is to create a nested template and attach the event template to it:

html:

```
<template name="tt">
  {{#each objs}}
    {{> inner}}
  {{/each}}
</template>

<template name="inner">
<h1>a={{a}}, b={{b}}</h1> 
{{#if yes}}
  <button class="b">b</button>{{yes}}
{{/if}}
</template>
```

js:

```
Template.inner.events({
  'click .b' (event, template) {
    console.log(this.a); //will be "a"
  } 
})
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it is weird I didnt find this workaround. So is this some kinda bug from meteor?

Comment: Not a bug. In an event handler `this` is the template's data context. If there is no specific data context then the context is the window object.